# Puma Rails server won't start in daemon mode on MacOS 13 Ventura after update from MacOS 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, puma, macos-ventura

I just updated from MacOS 12.x to 13.0.1

Starting a Rails app with

`➜ rails s`

works fine

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.8.1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

But when I try with

`➜ rails s -d`

Output stops at

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.8.1 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

And no server is started

```
➜ ps -ef | grep puma
501 69877 51917   0  6:45   ttys000    0:00.00 grep puma

➜ ps -ef | grep rails
501 72493 51917   0  6:49   ttys000    0:00.00 grep rails
```

Comment: can you try `rails s puma -d` ?

Comment: This does not launch a daemonized server either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround. This is by no means perfect but if it helps anyone with the same problem:

`nohup rails s </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

The `&` at the end will make it run in the background. All output/input goes to/from `/dev/null` and `nohup` makes sure it will run even after you quit the session.

Comment: An easier workaround is `nohup rails server --no-log-to-stdout >/dev/null &`, which does pretty much the same: `rails server --no-log-to-stdout &` put the server in background and stops the output (you don't have to mess with file descriptors), and `nohup >/dev/null` gets rid of the nohup.log file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason has nothing to do with the fact that you updated to MacOS Ventura.

[Puma daemonization has been removed without replacement since version 5.0.0](https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/2170), and it has been extracted to the [`puma-daemon` gem](https://github.com/kigster/puma-daemon), [which currently works only with Puma version ~> 5](https://github.com/kigster/puma-daemon/issues/10).

Therefore now you have two ways to make it work: with puma-daemon, or put it in no hanghup background mode.

---

**METHOD 1: USING PUMA DAEMON GEM**

1. `bundle add puma-daemon`
2. Add these line to your application’s `Gemfile`:

   `gem 'puma-daemon', require: false
   gem 'puma', '~> 5'`
3. Add these lines to `config/puma.rb`:

   `require 'puma/daemon'
   daemonize`

   and ensure you have set up at least one worker (`workers 1`)

Now you should be able to run puma webserver as a daemon with `rails server` (please notice that you must remove any `-d` or `--daemonize` from the command line)

---

**PUT IT IN NO HANGHUP BACKGROUND MODE**

Just run `rails server --no-log-to-stdout &` to put the server in background and stop the output, and enclose it in a `nohup >/dev/null` command to get rid of the nohup.log file:

`nohup rails server --no-log-to-stdout >/dev/null &`

This method works with any Puma version and doesn't require the gem.

---

**Don't mess around with the two ways.**

Comment: The gem solution does not apply to my case since I'm running old Rails 5 sites with Puma 3. Thanks ;)